# How to limit the data entered within a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I have a **stored procedure that prompts user for input** and stores/updates my table. My issue is that when trying to add limitations when entering number it does not work as planned.

**Here is the table:**

```
       Drop table incident;
       CREATE TABLE INCIDENT 
       (ICD_ID VARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       PLR_ID VARCHAR2 (11),
       M_ID VARCHAR2 (10),
       PP_ID VARCHAR2 (10),
       I_POINTS NUMBER (8));


       INSERT INTO INCIDENT VALUES
       ('ICD01', 'CHE01', 'M01', 'PP01', NULL);

       INSERT INTO INCIDENT VALUES
       ('ICD02', 'CHE03', 'M07', 'PP02', NULL);

       INSERT INTO INCIDENT VALUES
       ('ICD03', 'CHE03', 'M04', 'PP03', NULL);

       INSERT INTO INCIDENT VALUES
       ('ICD04', 'KLN04', 'M07', 'PP02', NULL);

       INSERT INTO INCIDENT VALUES
       ('ICD05', 'CHE01', 'M04', 'PP03', NULL);
```

When prompted, I enter the ICD_ID **(for example 'ICD03')** **must be capital** entry.

**The procedure:**

```
   DECLARE 
   v_icd_id incident.icd_id%type := &INCIDENT_ID; 
   v_inc_I_POINTS incident.i_points%type := &PENALTY_POINTS; 
   v_I_POINTS incident.I_POINTS%type;
   V_PP_ID INCIDENT.PP_ID%TYPE;    
   E_TOO_MANY_POINTS exception;
   E_UPDATE_HIGH exception;   
   E_A exception;
   E_B exception;
   E_C exception;
   BEGIN 
   SELECT I_POINTS INTO v_I_POINTS 
   FROM incident WHERE icd_id = v_icd_id;

   IF v_I_POINTS > 10 THEN 
   RAISE E_UPDATE_HIGH; 
   END IF;

   IF v_inc_I_POINTS >10 THEN
   RAISE E_TOO_MANY_POINTS; 
   END IF;


   IF V_PP_ID = 'PP03' OR V_INC_I_POINTS > 10 OR V_INC_I_POINTS < 10 THEN
   RAISE E_A;
   END IF;


  UPDATE incident SET i_points =  (v_inc_i_points + NVL(i_points,0))               
   WHERE icd_id=v_icd_id;



  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=====================');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PENALTY POINTS UPDATED!');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=====================');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');

  EXCEPTION 
  WHEN E_TOO_MANY_POINTS THEN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('==========================================================');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOO MANY POINTS ALLOCATED THERE! ACTION ABORTED.');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('==========================================================');


  WHEN E_UPDATE_HIGH THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=============================================================');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CAN NOT STORE THAT MANY PENALTY POINTS THERE! ACTION ABORTED.');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=============================================================');


  WHEN E_A THEN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=============================================================');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CAN ONLY ALLOCATED 10 POINTS HERE! ACTION ABORTED.');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=============================================================');


  WHEN E_B THEN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=============================================================');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CAN ONLY ALLOCATED 5 POINTS HERE! ACTION ABORTED.');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=============================================================');

  WHEN E_C THEN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=============================================================');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CAN ONLY ALLOCATED 1 POINTS HERE! ACTION ABORTED.');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=============================================================');

 END;
  /
```

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

Is to prevent people entering values of more than 10 and less than 10 where the PP_ID is "PP03".

**For this I applied:**

```
   IF V_PP_ID = 'PP03' OR V_INC_I_POINTS > 10 OR V_INC_I_POINTS < 10 THEN
   RAISE E_A;
   END IF;
```

**That works fine, but when I add another limitation like:**

To prevent people entering values of more than 5 and less than 5 where the PP_ID is "PP02".

```
    IF V_PP_ID = 'PP02' OR V_INC_I_POINTS > 5 OR V_INC_I_POINTS < 5 THEN
    RAISE E_B;
    END IF;
```

**OR**

To prevent people entering values of more than 1 and less than 1 where the PP_ID is "PP01".

```
    IF V_PP_ID = 'PP01' OR V_INC_I_POINTS > 1 OR V_INC_I_POINTS < 1 THEN
    RAISE E_C;
    END IF;
```

It does not work and only follows the first one. How can I overcome this? **Thanks in advance. Help is greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Have you considered implementing these restrictions as (domain) constraints?

Comment: I did yes, but I thought it is going be troublesome and decided to stick the limitations in the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your condition is incorrect:

`IF V_PP_ID = 'PP03' OR V_INC_I_POINTS > 10 OR V_INC_I_POINTS < 10 THEN` will evaluate to true whenever **V_PP_ID** equals 'PP03' (regardless of the value of V_INC_I_POINTS) AND whenever **V_INC_I_POINTS** is not equal to 10 (regardless of the value of V_PP_ID).

I believe the intended coniditon is:

`IF V_PP_ID = 'PP03' AND (V_INC_I_POINTS > 10 OR V_INC_I_POINTS < 10) THEN`

or simply:

`IF V_PP_ID = 'PP03' AND V_INC_I_POINTS != 10 THEN`

(The rest of your conditions regarding 'PP02' and 'PP01' should be modified accordingly.)

EDIT:

I missed it the first time, but it seems that "V_PP_ID" is never set to any value. We need to instanciate it to the value of the selected row's **PP_ID** column.

Try replacing:

```
SELECT I_POINTS INTO v_I_POINTS 
    FROM incident WHERE icd_id = v_icd_id;
```

with

```
SELECT I_POINTS, PP_ID INTO v_I_POINTS, V_PP_ID 
    FROM incident WHERE icd_id = v_icd_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, although it didnt change the outcome that I had initially (tried both of your suggestions).

Comment: Could you provide some results, e.g. with the following input combinations: v_icd_id = ICD03, v_inc_I_POINTS = {9, 10, 11} | v_icd_id = ICD02, v_inc_I_POINTS = {4, 5, 11} | v_icd_id = ICD01, v_inc_I_POINTS = {0, 1, 6}

Comment: Tried both of your examples, with the data you provided to input. Although it updates the points without any restrictions.

Comment: I spotted a second issue not addressed by my initial answer. Please, take a look at my edited answer and let us know if that worked :)

Comment: You dont know how much I appreciate your help, it worked! Thanks a bunch ES!

Comment: Hey, I am glad I helped too. This is my first accepted answer ever ! (I don't even know if that stuff is supposed to be on a comment, but if it isn't, I trust someone will edit it away :D)